# Error: -- :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED

Tags: java, android-studio

Acabo de abrir mi proyecto de *Android Studio* y al ejecutar el emulador me salta este error:

> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'.

¿Por qué puede ser?

No acabo de entenderlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
> 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'.

Tienes alguna dependencia en tu `build.gradle` que esta provocando el problema, te sugiero excluir el archivo mencionado dentro del bloque `android` > `packagingOptions` :

```
android {
    packagingOptions {           
        exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        

    }
}
```